# Why is it not advisable to jump onto the shore from a boat?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I have heard that we are not recommended to jump onto the shore from a boat Why? Is it because the boat may move backwards (water is fluid) and we will lose balance and fall into the water? Does this also explain why the boatman ties the boat before allowing the passengers to deboard?

**My Theory:** I think when I exert force on the boat in the backwards direction, the boat pushes me in the forward direction and I can jump onto the pier (Newton's third law). Is it correct?

Comment: ... and the boat shoots backwards. Is more noticeable in small skiffs without any other occupants (extra mass) to slow down the reaction of the boat.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is really more of a question of safety than physics.  Note that a sudden wave can throw your balance off or a wet surface can cause a slip.  Like all safety rules just because you've gotten away with it in the past does not mean you should keep doing it.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine these arepossible reasons, but these could be limited to specific warnings, like *Don't jump in stormy weather*. Besides, you can jump when the boat is tied - in fact, you often have no other choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that **the boat recoils**: when jumping from a hard surface one's force goes fully into accelerating the one's body, which determines how far one jumps/lands. When jumping from a boat, one's force is expended on accelerating oneself and the boat, which moves in the opposite direction. In other words, one's intuition (based on jumping from the hard surface) seemingly predicting how far one lands from the point of the jump, actually tells us how far one lands from the boat (which moved the other way.) This makes it easy to miscalculate the length of the jump with various unpleasant consequences.